# Merging data together based on specific conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset that consists of 5 columns. The first one being the patient, the second and third one being visit times and the fourth and fifth being the status of the patient at each visit. All these columns correspond with each other.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = c('Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave','Dave','Dave','Dave','Dave',   "Angel", "Angel", "Angel",   "Cara", "Cara"),
  V1 = c(1, 150, 240,430,530,650,800,        1, 150, 375,          1, 150),
  V2 = c(150, 240,430,530,650,800,900,       150, 375, 568,       150,375),
  R1 = c("Disease","Disease","Disease","Response","Response","Disease","Response",      "Disease","Response", "Response",    "Disease", "Response"),
  R2 = c("Disease", "Disease", "Response","Response","Disease","Response","Response",   "Response", "Response", "Response",   "Response", "Death"))
```

In this dataset I want to merge the rows that have the same status for each patient until we hit a change in their status. Then once the rows are merged I want to drop them. So I want my final dataset to have all rows where R1 ≠ R2 unless it is the last record. Essentially in terms of a loop (pseudocode)

```
if (r1 =r2 & not last record) { 
record v1 and r1 
walkthrough data until r1=r2 or last record 
record v2 and r2 
print }
```

But the solution does not have to be a loop I am open to other suggestions.

So my final dataset should look something like this:

```
| Patient  | V1  | V2  | R1     | R2
| Dave     |  1  | 430 |disease | response
| Dave     | 430 | 650 |response| disease
| Dave     | 650 | 800 |disease | response
| Dave     | 800 | 900 |response| response
| Angel    |  1  | 568 |disease |response
| Cara     |  1  | 375 |disease | death
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use tidyverse, it is great for these cleaning things.

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

Since you want to keep the last row, we can start by adding a row number for each patient which will tell us which one is the last row. The `group_by(Patient)` means do the following code for every single patient (i.e., basically the same as if you ran the code on multiple datasets, where each dataset was filtered for a different patient)

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(patient_id = row_number())
```

Next, we can filter for your conditions: R1 not equal to R2, but keep the last row:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(patient_id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(R1 != R2 | patient_id == max(patient_id)) # if this is true, then it is last row (since the dataset is still grouped)
```

Now all we need to do is to make the times match up.  There are two cases that I can think of:

1. The first row for each patient should be 1
2. Consecutive rows should have consecutive times

The first new line says if the patient id is the first one, then replace the start time with 1.
The second new line says for a given row, if there is a next start time, fill that with the current rows stop time, otherwise keep it as the stop time.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(patient_id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(R1 != R2 | patient_id == max(patient_id)) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(patient_id == min(patient_id), 1, V1)) %>%
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(lead(V1)), V2, lead(V1)))
```

Finally, we can clean up our dataset by removing added columns and ungrouping (what was caused by `goup_by()`)

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(patient_id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(R1 != R2 | patient_id == max(patient_id)) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(patient_id == min(patient_id), 1, V1)) %>%
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(lead(V1)), V2, lead(V1))) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-patient_id)

# Output:
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Patient    V1    V2 R1       R2      
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1 Dave        1   530 Disease  Response
2 Dave      530   650 Response Disease 
3 Dave      650   800 Disease  Response
4 Dave      800   900 Response Response
5 Angel       1   375 Disease  Response
6 Angel     375   568 Response Response
7 Cara        1   150 Disease  Response
8 Cara      150   375 Response Death
```

Which does not match your final dataset exactly, but you say you want to keep the last row which your final dataset doesn't have. So if there are any modifications you need to make, I think this code will give you a good start or ideas to try something else.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I only want to keep the last record if the status is same (r1=r2) depending if the record before has a status change where r1 does not equal r2. i need the solution to match the final dataset i have provided to cutout those middle entries. thanks for helping and i'll see what edits i can make to your solution to make it fit mine!